# How to set my mesa driver in a python script?

Tags: python, linux

I have to call MATLAB with "env MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965" in bash to use the hardware opengl rendering. I am using a neovim plugin that starts the MATLAB server via a python script. The line is

```
self.proc = Popen(["matlab", "-nosplash", "-nodesktop"], stdin=PIPE,
                              close_fds=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

I have tried to set global system environment variables and to insert this like

```
self.proc = Popen(["env MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965", "matlab", "-nosplash", 
"-nodesktop"], stdin=PIPE, close_fds=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

and also tried

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = 'env MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965'
```

None of them works. I never worked with Python and would just like to get MATLAB to work really.

Answer (score 1):

[Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) accepts `env` parameter. Just put necessary variables there:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE'] = 'i965'

self.proc = Popen(["matlab", "-nosplash", "-nodesktop"], stdin=PIPE,
                          close_fds=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid, env=env)
```

Comment: Thanks! I meanwhile found out that I could put: "env", "MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965", "matlab",...